# Alternative to an outer join to a subquery?

Tags: sql, oracle, scalar-subquery

Apparently outer-joins to a subquery are not allowed by Oracle. For each row on table A, I'm trying find the row on table B with the same ID, and latest date.

Something like this:

```
SELECT a.*, b.date, b.val1, b.val2
FROM a, b
WHERE b.id (+) = a.id
  AND b.date (+) = (SELECT MAX(b.date) FROM a, b WHERE a.id = b.id);
```

Removing the outer join (+) on b.date allows it to be parsed, but no rows are returned when there are no rows on table B. I need the query to just return NULL in this case. Is there a way around this?

Thanks

Comment: why can't you use `order by b.date desc`

Comment: Thanks - I need to select a couple other fields from B. Updated the question.

Comment: That's okay Since your concern is about the rows with latest date still u can use order by

Comment: Okay. I also need to select some matching rows from another table C. Could you give an example of how this would work? Thanks

Comment: You weren't totally clear about what you want to be null.  Do you want the date from B to be null if it isn't the max?  Or do you want everything from B to be null if the date isn't the max?

Answer (score 3):

I think what you want is this:

```
SELECT a.*, b.date, b.val1, b.val2
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b ON b.id = a.id
WHERE (b.date is null 
       or b.date = (SELECT MAX(b2.date) FROM b b2 WHERE a.id = b2.id));
```

This way, the outer join is just performed on `id`. Then we're filtering out all of the rows where `b.date` is not the `max` for the corresponding row in `a`.

As an aside, you'll note that I removed `a` from the sub-query. As originally written, the sub-query returned the largest date in `b` that had a corresponding row in `a`. The same value would be used for every row of the outer query. The revised version makes the sub-query correlate to the outer query (i.e. it will get the corresponding `max(date)` for each row returned).

Comment: This is a good answer and I'm upvoting it.  It might be more or less efficient than my answer depending on how many rows are in each table.

Comment: @DouglasBarbin: Our answers actually provide different results. Yours gets a single `max(date)` across all of the `b` table and mine gets the `max(date)` for each unique `b.id`. It's unclear based on the question which is the correct interpretation.

Comment: I just commented something similar on the OP.

Comment: Mine is also different in that it won't perform the join with B for the rows from A where the date isn't the max for the table.  Yours will always join on id, then eliminate rows based on whether or not the date in B is the max for a given id.  So the 2 queries are actually a bit more different than I initially realized.

Answer (score 3):

I already voted for Allan's answer, but just to demonstrate an alternative approach, here's how it can be done with an analytic function:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT a.*, b.date, b.val1, b.val2,
    ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY a.id ORDER BY b.date DESC) r
  FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON a.id=b.id
)
WHERE r=1
```

This will include only one row for each `a.id`, even if there are multiple `b` rows with the maximum date. To include all of them, change `ROW_NUMBER` to `RANK`.

Comment: I'm upvoting this becase it may outperform Allan's answer due to how `(<predicate> OR <sub-query>)` is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: You can save the max date to a variable

```
DECLARE @maxDate as datetime
SET @maxDate = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM b)

SELECT a.*, b.date, b.val1, b.val2
FROM a
LEFT OUTER JOIN b ON a.id = b.id
  AND b.date = @maxDate
```

This may be more or less efficient than Allan's answer, depending on if A has many more rows than B (or vice-versa).  If B has a ton of rows, then querying it twice (which my answer does) is probably not the best solution.

Comment: No - getting the error 'a column may not be outer-joined to a subquery'.

Comment: The OP has specified that this is an Oracle problem. This appears to be a SQL Server solution.

Comment: @Allan Yes, I don't normally use Oracle.  Is any of this non-standard SQL?

Comment: Oracle doesn't use the @ for variables and doesn't allow returning a result set out of a procedural block without the use of a cursor.

Comment: Ahhh, I learn something new every day.  I am far from a SQL guru.  Thanks for the knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

How about a scalar subquery?

```
select a.*, (select max(b.date) from b where b.id = a.id) as b_date
from a;
```

Comment: He needs a few other columns from B, and (I think) that he wants to only perform the join with the rows in B that have the max date.

Comment: I think you're right - but when I answered his question didn't want any other columns from B, that was added later!